# Tizen wearable templates explanation

Tags: c#, templates, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

Visual Studio Tools for Tizen provides, among other things, a set of templates. Among these are "Tizen Wearable App" and "Tizen Wearable Xaml App". Could somebody please explain the difference between these two? I get that obviously the core difference would be the use of xaml for creating the UI, but what does that really mean? In what situations would I want to use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, no difference between them, just difference that App class was made by XML or C# code, you can make UI with XML whatever you choose which template.